# g_socket_bind behavior on UDP multicast

Tags: network-programming, multicast, glib

I have multiple readers on a single system which bind to a single address (IP:port ex. 239.0.0.1:1234). Another computer on group sends a UDP multicast packet to this group and readers should receive it. I used GLib 2.0 networking stack, `g_socket_bind` with `allow_reuse` set to `true`.

When there is a single reader (single socket binded to that address) or up to three readers everything is ok and readers will receive packets correctly. But when the number of readers increases to four or above, the packet loss occurs and linearly increases with number of readers on system.

> If socket is a UDP socket, then allow_reuse determines whether or not other UDP sockets can be bound to the same address at the same time. In particular, you can have several UDP sockets bound to the same address, and they will all receive all of the multicast and broadcast packets sent to that address.

As stated in [GIO Reference Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSocket.html#g-socket-listen), when allow_reuse set true, all readers should read all of data but it doesn't happen as the stated above.

Anybody knows what the problem is? Is there a kernel related problem?

Comment: Are your receive handlers slow? That could explain UDP packet loss if theres also enough traffic...  If they are you could debug by disabling the slow processing just to see if you still get packet loss.

Comment: no, the receive handlers aren't slow, i tested them without any processing, but the failure still exists

Answer (score 1):

All your sockets need to join the multicast group. If you're just relying on the bind to effect that, you are into undefined behaviour.